# How to fight the startover effect

Tags: debugging, design-patterns

When I'm asked to fix a bug or introduce a feature in a project I did not develope I often have this feeling that starting from scratch would safe me a lot of work, pain and effort. Altougth often this obviously is more work and seems like I suffer greatly from [nih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

So, what are ways you fight this urge and focus on the project or enable yourself to morph the project bit by bit to something you like more while fixing bugs or introducing features?

### To make some points about me:

- I'm a fairly good programmer
- I would consider myself a python programmer, meaning I try to follow the [Zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)
- I don't really like big abstraction (more in the example below)
- Obviously sometimes I have that problem with my own code.

### To make some points about the projects I talk about:

- Lately most of them are based on php but might be any language
- Propably coded by someone who never really coded big projects or in teams
- Most often with a lot of classes and pseudo-abstraction (more below)
- Most likely without comments at all
- Bad named variables, classes and functions
- A lot of redundancy for instance a lot of `style="border:1px solid black"`
  or the same javascript function with different names in every htm file, or classes that will call each other in turns
- Huge switch statements over like a couple of hundreds of lines
- Sometimes build atop of librarys that are deprecated or just way to big for serving a very small feature set.
- Huge Codebase without really splitting up the codes in different files
- Weird globals
- Dead code in weird places (like in the switch statements)

### How I try to solve it:

Lately if I have to fix something I will do so and after finding out what happens and being anoyed by it, I will put a lot of `#TODO`s in there and fix the initial problem.   Often with this method I use the predefined functions or classes that by their name should do something completely different, making the project more horrific.

Comment: what is the question again? Surely many people will be able to related to you, but tell us how we can help you?

Comment: Now that you've gotten that out -- edit it down to a question.

Comment: How long have you been developing?

Comment: Hmm, don't consider yourself a good programmer when you don't know how to migrate legacy code into a target architecture. An answer would be too long for SO, so here's a suggested course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/brownfield

Comment: @PeteBelford I programm now for like 10 years or more, but I just work as programmer since 4 years.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Maybe I'm vague if I say I'm a good programmer. By this I mean I can code well. This does not mean that I am great at software development or reading other peoples code, althougth I wouldn't say I'm in particular bad at it.

Comment: But a lot of software really needs replaced. I'd go so far as "most" of it. The trick is to replace it with something better.

Answer (score 2):

> So what are ways you fight this urge and focus on the project or enable yourself to morph the project bit by bit to something you like more while fixing bugs or introducing features?

What worked for me:

1. Try to re-program a medium sized software (maybe 10000 to 20000 lines of code), then end up with something only marginally better than the original and absolutely not worth the effort you have put into it.
2. Learn about refactoring methods. You will soon notice that refactoring - when done right - is not just monotonous work but can be just as interesting and challenging as starting a new project. And that it is usually much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a really good question. All of us have gone thru this, and everyone thinks everyone else's code is, well, sub-standard.

I try to keep my customer in mind. On one hand, my customer isn't well-served by poorly-architected or -designed code and I can swoop in and fix that. But on the other hand, if it works, he may also not be well-served by paying me lots of money to re-do something that already works.

Can I "sneak" better stuff in? Unit tests? Small refactorings? Sometimes long, complex methods are that way because they've been tweaked over time - there are bug-fixes in there that I might break if I'm not careful.

Comment: Exactly my problem, if I do some small refactorings, hell will break loose.

Comment: @mjb4 The what you are refactoring should be trashed. It is costing you more to maintain than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

A developer with four of five years professional experience is starting to "hit their stride".  He or she is becoming competent enough to see the bigger picture of a project.  You are probably 100% correct in your self-assessment, and your desire to learn from others will set you apart.

Keep this in mind:  programming is hard and it is almost always done under duress.  Duress manifests itself in several forms:  apathy, new technical skill, boredom, tight deadlines, personal issues, tiredness.

For example I discovered a problem caused by the lead programmer where I work.  He is an incredibly smart person that has the technical skills necessary.  The problem:  he spec'd out a web service in the singular form of a word, but implemented the call in the plural.  In other words, spec:  /offload_file; implementation:  /offload_files.

It's kind of a huge issue despite the one character mistake in a document that is well over 20K words.  His duress:  his wife is getting ready to give birth.

You have achieved a level of technical skill that few are able, now you have to do learn to do something different. You have to figure out how to work within a team.

You will encounter people that have more experience and less technical skill with no desire to improve.  How do you work with them?  You will encounter stake holders who can barely operate a light switch lecture you on the proper color of a server for optimal performance.  How do you work with them?  Scott Adams (Dilbert) made a small fortune poking fun at the people programmers deal with.

As you pointed out you will need to learn to balance your tactical responsibilities (adding functionality) with strategic improvements (re-factoring code).  Making strategic decisions are not to be taken lightly, as you have discovered it can have catastrophic effects on production software.

You have climbed a hill of knowledge to discover that you still have many, many things to learn.  Keep going and be understanding.  There are no easy answers.  The fact that there are no easy answers makes this career field so lucrative.